# MongoDB msi installer crashes in "repair" mode

Tags: mongodb

I have downloaded the latest stable `mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-4.0.3-signed.msi` and installed on a fresh `w2k16` system. Right after that, I run installation again and choose "repair", and installation failed with a strange 
[image: error] and then [another error windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbTAf.jpg)

This msi file installation will be a part of our product installation guide, so I wondering that users can get the same issues if running mongodb installation twice.

Installation steps:
1) Run mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-4.0.3-signed.msi
2) Choose "Custom" button
3) Accept all default [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kP1g.jpg)
4) Wait for install to complete
5) Run mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-4.0.3-signed.msi again
6) Choose "Repair"

Any ideas about this issue and how we can fix/workaround it?

Comment: Did you specify to install as a service? I've been unable to duplicate your error (albeit in 2008R2 instead of W2K16). What options did you choose when you install it?

Comment: I have updated my first post. Yes, I choose all default settings, with installing service.